# Sorting accNo field which are from two different path

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<accountList>
    <previousAccount>
        <account>
            <name>NASH</name>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>1</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>ADOGA</name>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>8</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>LUCAS</name>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>09</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>DONALD</name>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>21</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <Title>Miss</Title>
            <firstName>HILARI</firstName>
            <lastName>WOOD</lastName>
            <city>LONDON</city>
            <accNo>24</accNo>
        </account>
    </previousAccount>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>RICHARD</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>london</city>
        <accNo>02</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>London</city>
        <accNo>17</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>HEWIT</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>20</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>21</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>KEVIN</firstName>
        <lastName>PETE</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>07</accNo>
    </account>
</accountList>
```

> xslt code

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform file:/C:/Users/n434947/Desktop/workspace/SonicXSLT/BA xslt page.xsd"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:variable name="newline">
 <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="accountList">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="descendant::account" group-starting-with="*[firstName != 'xxx' or lastName != preceding-sibling::*[1]/lastName]">
            <xsl:sort select="accNo" order="ascending"/>
            <xsl:if test="previousAccount/account/accountStatus='REMOVED'">
            <xsl:value-of select="previousAccount/account[accountStatus='REMOVED']/accNo"/>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="previousAccount/account[accountStatus='HOLD']/accNo"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="accNo"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>

            <xsl:value-of select="lastName"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="firstName"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my requirement ,I got to sort accNo which are all from two different X paths like below

```
accountList/previousAccount/account/accNo
accountList/account/accNo
```

I used descendant,which is not working fine for my requirement. Please help me to sort out this please.

Actual Output

```
02 JOHN RICHARD
07 PETE KEVIN
1 
20 JOHN HEWIT
24 WOOD HILARI
```

Expecting output

```
   01 REMOVED   NASH
   02           JOHN RICHARD
   07           PETE KEVIN
   08 REMOVED   ADOGA
   09 HOLD      LUCAS
   20           JOHN HEWIT
   24 HOLD       DONALD
```

Comment: Please help me ,i tried to sort out by two select in for-each,,which not giving the proper results ...

Answer (score 0):

> In my requirement ,I got to sort accNo which are all from two
>   different X paths like below
>
> ```
> accountList/previousAccount/account/accNo
> accountList/account/accNo
> ```

Maybe you can do it where you don't have two different XPaths. If you reduce your XPaths above, by removing `previousAccount` you see that they basically the same. You just need to search descendants of `accountList`...

```
accountList//account/accNo
```

If you do this with an `xsl:for-each` or an `xsl:apply-templates` your sorting becomes easier. Any additional filtering, like `firstName != 'xxx'` can be added to the predicate.

I think this is what you were originally trying, but it fell apart with `xsl:for-each-group`.

Here's an example ([also seen here](http://xsltransform.net/ncntCTi)). I'm completely guessing at the actual format of the output; especially the padding of the fields. I probably over complicated it a bit, but it should be a start at least.

**XML Input**

```
<accountList>
    <previousAccount>
        <account>
            <name>NASH</name>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>1</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>ADOGA</name>
            <accountStatus>REMOVED</accountStatus>
            <accNo>8</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>LUCAS</name>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>09</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <name>DONALD</name>
            <accountStatus>HOLD</accountStatus>
            <accNo>21</accNo>
        </account>
        <account>
            <Title>Miss</Title>
            <firstName>HILARI</firstName>
            <lastName>WOOD</lastName>
            <city>LONDON</city>
            <accNo>24</accNo>
        </account>
    </previousAccount>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>RICHARD</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>london</city>
        <accNo>02</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>London</city>
        <accNo>17</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>HEWIT</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>20</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>xxx</firstName>
        <lastName>JOHN</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>21</accNo>
    </account>
    <account>
        <Title>Mr</Title>
        <firstName>KEVIN</firstName>
        <lastName>PETE</lastName>
        <city>LONDON</city>
        <accNo>07</accNo>
    </account>
</accountList>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:l="local" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:function name="l:pad">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="l:pad($input,$length,'right')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="l:pad">
    <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="align" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="inputLength" select="string-length($input)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="padding" select="if ($length > $inputLength) then 
      for $x in 1 to ($length - $inputLength) return ' ' else ''"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="if ($align = 'right') then 
      string-join(($padding,$input),'') else
      string-join(($input,$padding),'')"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//account[not(firstName = 'xxx')]">
      <xsl:sort select="accNo" data-type="number"/>
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="l:pad(
        l:pad(format-number(accNo,'00'),5),6,'left')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="l:pad(
        concat(accountStatus,' '),10,'left')"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="l:pad(
        string-join((lastName,name|firstName),' '),20,'left')"/>      
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output** (it wasn't obvious to me why "WOOD HILARI" was supposed to be excluded)

```
   01 REMOVED   NASH                
   02           JOHN RICHARD        
   07           PETE KEVIN          
   08 REMOVED   ADOGA               
   09 HOLD      LUCAS               
   20           JOHN HEWIT          
   21 HOLD      DONALD              
   24           WOOD HILARI
```

Comment: Just noticed how old this question was! Oh well, hopefully it helps someone in the future.